# c# how to get control which modifier is private

Tags: c#

i have a custom control in a form which is  `private`.

In the other form i have code like this

```
foreach(Form f in Application.OpenForms)
```

one of the forms is `Formthatcontaincontrols`,

`Formthatcontaincontrols` contains the custom control which is `private`, i need to access that customcontrol from form `"f"`

Comment: Why you dont expose the control(s) via public property?

Comment: because there are around 40 forms which has that custom control set to private, 
can't change all of them ,so i need a solution

Comment: Ofcourse you can, but in case you cannot, do these form have a common ancestor, maybe you could create a public method allowing you to access that property

Comment: If you have so many similar Forms which all hold the same CustomControl you should have made another CustomControl which is the parent of all others. Then you dont have this code duplication

Answer (score 2):

You could expose the control via public property:

In `Formthatcontaincontrols`

```
public TheCustomControlYouWant TheCustomControl
{
    get { return this.CustomControl; }
}
```

Then you can access this property:

```
foreach(Formthatcontaincontrols f in Application.OpenForms.OfType<Formthatcontaincontrols>())
{
    TheCustomControlYouWant ctrl = f.TheCustomControl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do not expose implementation details when using controls.

From the perspective of the consumer of your parent custom control (`Formthatcontaincontrols`), implementation details should be hidden.

I assume you need to access some kind of property which is important for the consumer of the `Formthatcontaincontrols`.

I advise just to expose this property and let the control itself find the relevant child and access the inner property defined in the child control.

You can find `Formthatcontaincontrols` using the solution pasted by @Tim Schmelter.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore all the controls in the form:

```
private List<T> FindControls<T>(Control.ControlCollection controls) where T: Control
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    foreach (Control control in controls)
    {
        var matched = control as T;
        if (matched != null)
            list.Add(matched);
        else
            list.AddRange(FindControls<T>(control.Controls));
    }
    return list;
}
```

For example, you can search all buttons with this:

```
foreach (var btn in FindControls<Button>(yourForm.Controls))
{
    Trace.WriteLine(btn.Name);
}
```